# How to do mongoid 'not_in' 'greater than' query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, cucumber, mongoid, database

If I want to search a mongoid model **with** attribute greater than 100 I would do this.

```
Model.where({'price' => {'$gt' => 100}})
```

How do I do search a mongoid model **without** attribute greater than 100?

Tried this and failed.

```
Model.not_in({'price' => [{'$gt' => 100}]})
```

Additional info:

In the end of the day would like to make a query like so:

```
criteria = {
    'price' => [{'$gt' => 100}],
    'size'  => 'large',
    'brand' => 'xyz'    
}

Model.not_in(criteria)
```

As the criteria would be dynamically created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

model without attribute greater than 100 = model with attribute less than or equal to 100?

```
Model.where({'price' => {'$lte' => 100}})
```

Comment: That would be a great answer if I was just doing this.  But I would like to have lots of other attributes. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Model.where(:price.lte => 100,:size.ne => 'large',:brand.ne => 'xzy')
```

Comment: Hmm, I as hoping to keep the criteria interface the same, as I am building a smart search where it takes two hash parameters. First hash would be for the attributes required the second hash would be for the attributes not needed.  And there are quite a few helper methods that are used by both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.ne()` (not equals) operator

```
Model.where({:price.lte => 100}).ne({:size => 'large', :brand => 'xzy'})
```

You can also find the Mongoid documentation here http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#negation

Comment: Very interesting!  I didn't know we can chain search like this.  But unfortunately my question is how to do 'not_in' or 'ne' with the 'greater than' operation which doesn't work.

Comment: By boolean logic, 'not_in' or 'ne' with the 'greater than' symbol is equivalent to 'less than or equals'. 

Also if you look at their examples, they use a symbol for the key. But it really makes no difference whether you use a symbol or string as the key. You can use the syntax `:price.lte => 100`, `'price'.lte => 100`, or `'price.lte' => 100`

Comment: Yes I would like to do both "greater than" and "less than".  But the problem is, it does not work with "not_in" or "ne" as far as I know.